# Create ActiveMQ Artemis broker with command line only

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm trying to create an ActiveMQ Artemis broker instance using the command-line only but it seems that `allow-anonymous` option is ignored and the question "Allow anonymous?" comes anyway after I run the `create` command like this:

```
./artemis-2.17.0/bin/artemis create --user=test --password=test --allow-anonymous=Y ./broker-name
```

What is the right way to pass the `allow-anonymous` option and avoid to get that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this command you will see all the available options for the `create` command:

```
artemis help create
```

One of these options is `--allow-anonymous`. This doesn't need to be set to any value. Also the options which do take a value do not need the equal sign (`=`). Therefore, your command should look like this:

```
artemis create --user test --password test --allow-anonymous ./broker-name
```